# I want to have a SQL computed column according to rules

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, case, calculated-columns

I want to be able to store a decimal value in one column, and in the other column to store an int that represents the option (will explain):

1. should be base -%
2. should be base -absolute
3. should be base +%
4. should be base +absolute
5. 1 & 2 is a discount
6. 3 & 4 is an upcharge
7. 1 & 3 reduces/raises the amount by percentage (i.e. amount * amount/value).
8. 2 & 4 reduces/raises the amount absolutely (i.e. amount +/- value).

Meaning I have a table of 3 columns:

- BasePrice money
- AdditionalPrice decimal
- Option tinyint

and

- ComputedColumn (decimal?)

let's say we have a row that it's BasePrice is 100 and the AdditionalPrice is 0.20

According to the option the computed col should generate the following value:

- 80
- 99.80
- 120
- 100.20

Am I clear?
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Personally, I would steer away from the MONEY data type.  What does it buy you, that DECIMAL doesn't?  I blogged about the myths of MONEY's superior performance last year:  http://is.gd/4BrRI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd keep the computed column as money too.

Internally, this will cast to decimal because of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE (
...,
ComputedColumn AS CAST (
    CASE Option
        WHEN 1 THEN BasePrice * (1 - AdditionalPrice)
        WHEN 2 THEN BasePrice - AdditionalPrice
        WHEN 3 THEN BasePrice * (1 + AdditionalPrice)
        WHEN 4 THEN BasePrice + AdditionalPrice
    END AS money)
)
```